# Do not print a particular field on first page of the report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on crystal reports. I want to avoid printing a field on the first page of the report, but print it on rest of the pages. I am also resetting the page number at group level. So if I suppress the field on page 1 it also suppresses on the page where the new group starts and the page number is reset to 1, which I don’t want.

Answer (score 0):

If the field is suppressed on this condition:

```
RecordNumber = 1
```

it should behave like you want, i.e. it's not shown on the very first page, regardless of the CR page numbering.

Note: this one will only work if the second record started on page 1, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like you are using a formula to suppress the field when `PageNumber = 1`, and it is suppressing the field on the first page of the report, but when you get to the next record in the group the page number resets to 1 and the field is suppressed again, when you want it to be shown.

I would try updating the suppression formula to the following.

```
PageNumber = 1 AND GroupNumber = 1
```

If you have multiple levels of grouping in your data, things can get a little interesting though.  The `GroupNumber` function does not allow you to specify which group it is enumerating and instead returns record number for the inner most group that the function is contained within.